# Remove empty space from number string?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to remove any white space in the number from the textbox (txtAllNum) before converting them into an array. But I got the `Input string was not in a correct format.` error at the attempt to convert them to array.

Please advice.

(The list of numbers which will be inserted already have spaces at the beginning so I can't reject them with validation)

```
string allNumStr = txtAllNum.Text;
allNumStr = allNumStr.Replace(" ", "");

var intAry = allNumStr
   .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, 
          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   .Select(s => Int64.Parse(s));
```

Here is the sample input data (They have a spaces at the beginning)

> 95949323114
>    9592099619
>    9595173327
>    95943054737
>    95943090230
>    95991046911
>    9595028775
>    95943173776
>    95973494329
>    95973082074
>    95973000239

Comment: Care to provide a sample of what the input looks like?

Comment: Have you considered using `Trim` in case those spaces are  at the ends?

Comment: So what is the problem you face?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I've updated the question with sample input data.

Comment: @V4Vendetta Spaces will be at the beginning.

Comment: I took your sample input and your code and could not reproduce your error. However, that is not to say it does not exist, it could be an environmental issue (such as `NewLine` not actually matching the input line breaks). Break your code down into steps, and then debug it and see what each line produces. Specifically, create the string array in one statement, put a breakpoint on it and see what's in the array. Does that look right? I suspect it will not. After verifying and fixing that, then do the conversion to long.

Comment: If the string array looks right, then the next area is that an element of it is malformed for the long conversion. Again, step through, which input is causing the parse to blow up? Nothing in your sample should, there are no illegal characters, but there's the possibility you are not showing us the whole thing.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Thank you so much for the advices. Even though I've already got a way to fix (Thanks to Uwe Keim), I'll see where it goes wrong. And yes, the input data is much more.

Comment: Anthony is right. Int64.Parse allows whitespace on either side anyway. The only issue I can see would be having nothing but a tab on a line (My answer would account for that). Using the sample data given and the original code I encountered no errors and received correct outcome even after removing the second line. Perhaps the real cause is in some other data you haven't listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, would a simple [`TrimStart()` call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx) help?

```
string allNumStr = txtAllNum.Text;
allNumStr = allNumStr.Replace(" ", "");

var intAry = allNumStr
   .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, 
          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   .Select(s => Int64.Parse(s.TrimStart()));
```

Comment: This assumes there won't be a completely blank or completely whitespace line.

Comment: @McAden Take a look at his sample data.

Comment: @McAden, removing empty entries accounts for that. That said, I'm surprised this actually resolves the issue. It... shouldn't, unless there's whitespace other than a space at the beginning of the input. His sample data certainly doesn't reveal the problem, so I cannot say for sure this would or wouldn't solve it. But if the OP says it does, it must! +1 for psychic debugging, I suppose.

Comment: This resolves for the sample data yes, but it's still user input so it does need to be a little more flexible than that. There's also no code there removing empty entries. Besides, this shouldn't be any different than the OP's code except that it accounts for other leading whitespace (a leading tab for example). His first line should take care of every space. This doesn't account for blank entries or trailing whitespace.

Comment: Correction: it doesn't account for blanks that are made of spaces other than simple spaces. Putting in a line that is nothing but a tab or adding a tab at the end of any of the lines will break.

Comment: Yes, a line that is simply a tab should break. A line that contains a tab would be fine as long as it was otherwise a valid number. Of course, a line with `\t12345` would be valid for Int64.Parse anyway, the method is robust enough to ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding in a Where should do the trick. I have compiled this and tested this and it accounts for both leading and trailing whitespace, as well as blank entries.

Also, this assumes .Net 4 (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace). You'll need to change the where statement if using anything less.

```
string allNumStr = txtAllNum.Text;
var intAry = allNumStr
    .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    .Select(s => Int64.Parse(s.Trim()));
```